# How can I convert this to DATETIME SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, datetime

Trying to convert this value to `DATETIME` and unsuccessful so far. Thoughts and ideas are welcome.

```
03MAR2020:02:45:58.977000
```

Comment: Date functions are higly database-specific. Please tag your question with the database you are using: myql, oracle, postgresql...?

Comment: Apologies, we're suing MySQL

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) with the proper format:

```
select str_to_date('03MAR2020:02:45:58.977000', '%d%b%Y:%k:%i:%s.%f')
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sHZXSifvBx81QJHJNyHiZK/0).
Result:

```
2020-03-03 02:45:58.977000
```

Answer (score 0):

in SQL Server

03MAR2020:02:45:58.977000  is failing to convert tot `datetime` because, first there is an extra `:` sign after the year and the fractional seconds is 6 digits instead of max 3.

If the string is always the same length and the same format, then you can use the following to solve this problem:

```
DECLARE @example varchar(25) = '03MAR2020:02:45:58.977000'
SET @example = LEFT(@example, 22)   --- remove last 3 zeros
SET @example = STUFF(@example, CHARINDEX(':', @example), LEN(':'), ' ')  ---repalce the first ':'
SELECT convert(datetime, @example) --- convert to datetime
```

More details: Here are the parts of `datetime` data type in SQL Server.

```
YYYY is four digits from 1753 through 9999 that represent a year.

MM is two digits, ranging from 01 to 12, that represent a month in the specified year.

DD is two digits, ranging from 01 to 31 depending on the month, that represent a day of the specified month.

hh is two digits, ranging from 00 to 23, that represent the hour.

mm is two digits, ranging from 00 to 59, that represent the minute.

ss is two digits, ranging from 00 to 59, that represent the second.

n* is zero to three digits, ranging from 0 to 999, that represent the fractional seconds.
```

Taken from the SQL server documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Realized the question was for MySQL. I answered for SQL Server. I'm leaving it up here in case it is helpful to someone